# How to use .indexOf inside a for of loop in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, indexof, tic-tac-toe

I'm a beginner to JavaScript working on my first project: Tic Tac Toe!

I'm trying to write a function that will use a for/of loop to look through all the spaces on the game board and return an array of numbers corresponding with the index of any space that has an X in it.

`spaceArray` is the game board, with random x's in it for now.

Here is my attempt at the function:

```js
var s = '_'
var x = 'X'
var O = 'O'
var spaceArr = [s, s, s, x, s, s, s, s, x]

function spaceChecker(array) {
  let currGame = []
  for (var element of array) {
    if (element === 'X')
      currGame.push(array.indexOf(element))
  }
  return currGame
}
console.log(spaceChecker(spaceArr))
```

It currently returns:

```
[ 3, 3 ]
```

How can I get `.indexOf` to update each time the for/of loops?

Answer (score 1):

You have used `indexOf` which will return the first index of the `X` every time you are searching for `X`. If you want to use `for..of` loop then you have to track the `index` at which you are on.

```js
var s = "_";
var x = "X";
var O = "O";
var spaceArr = [s, s, s, x, s, s, s, s, x];

function spaceChecker(array) {
  let currGame = [];
  let index = 0;
  for (var element of array) {
    if (element === "X") {
      currGame.push(index);
    }
    index++;
  }
  return currGame;
}
console.log(spaceChecker(spaceArr));
```

**`ALTERNATE SOLUTION ⬇`**

You can just use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) here to get the index of the `X` in an array

```js
var s = "_";
var x = "X";
var O = "O";
var spaceArr = [s, s, s, x, s, s, s, s, x];

function spaceChecker(array) {
  return array.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
    if (curr === "X") acc.push(index);
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
console.log(spaceChecker(spaceArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you do not need to return anything from the loop you can use forEach loop.

```
forEach((element, index) => {
   // if condition met push index in custom array
});
```

Comment: Oh cool! I haven't used that type of loop yet, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

> [The indexOf() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns *the first index* at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

So your code will always return `3` because that will be the first index where `X` is found on every iteration.

It's much easier to use a basic for/loop and push the index of the current iteration into `currGame` when `X` is found.

```js
const s = '_';
const x = 'X';
const O = 'O';

const spaceArr = [s, s, s, x, s, s, s, s, x];

function spaceChecker(array) {
  const currGame = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === 'X') currGame.push(i);
  }
  return currGame;
}

console.log(spaceChecker(spaceArr));
```

Comment: Nice, that's way easier! Thanks so much.

Comment: The documentation on MDN for [loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) is comprehensive. @MaxWaters